# Configuration file for Cloudera Management Service

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager

Is the a configuration file for [Cloudera Management Service](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/properties/5-16-x/topics/cm_props_mgmtservice.html#concept_5.16.x_clouderamanagementservice_props)?

I'd like to have the service roles' configuration stored in repository. This way, service configuration can be shared between environments without the need to change the configuration via CM ui or rest API on each environment.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudera deploys configs for those dynamically when service is started by agent, for example Service Monitor will end up in `/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/XXXXX-cloudera-mgmt-SERVICEMONITOR`
Config itself is stored in database, in `configs` table.

So I would say that your only solution (sadly) is to manage config via api. Client libraries for that are pretty friendly though.